# What class selectors should I use to affect these odd-numbered elements?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Here is the page I am affecting:
http://www.careerchoiceswithlaura.com/blog/

Inspecting the elements will show that I set up one class "blog-post" and added it to each entry on the page. Then, I use a simple algorithm to apply a class named "even-numbered" or "odd-numbered" as well for appropriate entries so I can stagger the color effects and make the page more readable.

The problem is, that when I apply rules using the following line in my CSS file:

```
.blog-post .odd-numbered { background: #ddd; }
```

..it doesn't affect the elements with both blog-post and odd-numbered; in fact, the rule affects nothing on the page.

Could someone explain why, and which class selectors I should be using to affect said elements?

I researched online, and find [this article at W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) very helpful usually (and it appears that the rule should be working if you look at /blog/:279 on the page I mentioned above), but even with the rule there it doesn't seem to be anything to the elements I am trying to target.

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer by clicking the check mark to the left of the question you want to accept!

Comment: @coreyward :o I clicked it once - I must've missed. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example selector targets elements with the class `odd-numbered` that have an ancestor element with the class `blog-post`.

In your HTML, the `.blog-post` element is also the `.odd-numbered` element.

Your selector, then, should be `.blog-post.odd-numbered` (note the lack of a space).

Answer (score 2):

You'll want these CSS pseudo-selectors:

```
elementname:nth-child(even)
```

and

```
elementname:nth-child(odd)
```

Documentation:
http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd

Comment: This is another valid way of doing it, but it isn't supported in all browsers. It would have been nice if you elaborated on how the asker could implement this in his case since he's clearly not familiar.

Answer (score 2):

To style the same element with two classnames, you will want (without a space):

```
.blog-post.odd-numbered { background: #ddd; }
```

You original style, with a space, styles an element with the class `odd-numbered` **inside** an element with the class `blog-post`

Answer (score 1):

from [CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo)

```
:nth-child(odd)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should apply as `.blog-post.odd-numbered { background: #ddd; }` without space btw css classes, If it is applied to same element.